# Nginx `location /` does not match `/some_path`

Tags: nginx, location

Help me pls to configure nginx: I want nginx return `index.html` for all URLs like `10.10.256.142/`, `10.10.256.142/some_path` and `10.10.256.142/other_path/lala`. Problem: currently it returns `index.html`only for `10.10.256.142/` URL.

My current settings

```
listen 80;
server_name  10.10.256.142; 
server_name_in_redirect  off;
resolver  127.0.0.1;

location / {
    error_page 405 =200 $uri;
    root   /some_path/project_dir;
    index  index.html index.htm;
}

location /websocket {
    # ....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, simplest solution would be:

```
root /some_path/project_dir;

location / {
    rewrite ^ /index.html break;
}

location /websocket/ {
    # ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! May you explain how it would work please?

Comment: your code doesn't work since nginx stop returning static assets (`assets/bundle.js`) and return `inedx.html` instead

Comment: You've missed that part in your question

Comment: my bad. I think that instead `rewrite ^` I should write regexp like `rewrite <everything_except_/assets/_regexp>`. Is that right? How can  I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Just to complete the answer above and return static assets I had to write

```
root  /srv/www/betbull;
location / {
    if ($uri !~ (/assets/.*)) { # do not return index.html instead of static assets
        rewrite ^ /index.html break;
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE**:

Better solution:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ index.html$query_string
}
```